# print a table on php from data retrieved from xml

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to print a table with the list of customer oder from data retrieved from an xml file. I think my attempt at retrieving data has failed as it did not show anything. I also wanted to add two buttoms at the end of each order (delet and edit):

```html
<?php 
// Loading the XML file
$xml = simplexml_load_file("database/orderlist.xml");

echo "
<div style='overflow-x:auto;'>
<table id='order'>
  <tr>
   
    <th>Order #</th>  
    <th>Customer ID# </th>
    <th>Items</th>
    <th>Total Prices (CND)</th>
    

  </tr>
    foreach($xml->children() as $ftpxml)
    {
        echo '<td>".$ftpxml->attributes()->id."</td>';
        echo '<td> ".$ftpxml->attributes()->customerID." </td>';
        echo '<td>".$ftpxml->attributes()->products." </td>';
        echo '<td>".$ftpxml->attributes()->totalprice." </td>';
        echo '<a href="backStoreOrderProfile.html" ><button class="btn Edit" id="btn" input value="Check" type=submit > Edit </button></a>';
        echo '<button class="btn Delete" id="btn" input value="Check" type=submit > Delete</button></td>';
    }
    </table>
    </div>
    ";
?>
```

Comment: thank you very much for answering! I fixed it but still some errors showing on the </table> tag tho

Comment: thanks Ken. still it could not recognize attributes. it printed the codes such as .$ftpxml->attributes()->id. instead

Comment: change **ALL** '<td>" to `'<td>'` and **ALL** "</td>' to `'</td>'` please

Comment: hey Ken sorry to be a bother I still had trouble printing out a table. i am pretty new to this forum i dont know how to add more codes to my original question. but you could find my xml file here:https://jsfiddle.net/caizhangbin/eqLt8dp1/1/

Comment: I have read your XML file and amended your code (please see my answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems in your codes

1. make sure you end each php statement by a semi-colon
2. make sure you enclose the string in same quotation marks
3. make sure you traverse the XML hierarchy properly

```
<?php
// Loading the XML file
$xml = simplexml_load_file("database/orderlist.xml");
echo "
<div style='overflow-x:auto;'>
<table border=1 cellpadding=5 id='order' style='border-collapse: collapse;' bordercolor='#DDDDDD'>
  <tr>
   
    <th>Order #</th>  
    <th>Customer ID# </th>
    <th>Items</th>
    <th>Total Prices (CND)</th>
    <th>Edit
    <th>Delete
    

</tr>";
foreach ($xml->oder as $ftpxml) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $ftpxml->id; ?>
<td><?php echo $ftpxml->customerID; ?>
<td>
    <?php
    foreach ($ftpxml->products->product as $ftpxml2) {
        echo $ftpxml2->productName . " ";
    } ?>
<td>
    <?php echo $ftpxml->totalprice; ?>

<?php
    echo '<td><a href="backStoreOrderProfile.html" ><button class="btn Edit" id="btn" input value="Check" type=submit > Edit </button></a>';
    echo '<td><button class="btn Delete" id="btn" input value="Check" type=submit > Delete</button></td>';
?>

<?php
} ?>
```